# fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory Theano and anaconda

Tags: python, c++, gcc, redhat, anaconda

I have issues with theano. Indeed I have access to a High Performance Computing server with an old version of gcc (4.4.6), python (2.6) and kernel (2.6.32). 
 
The issue is that I need to run a python 3 script that uses gensim and teano and I have no root access. 
 
 
To address the issue I installed Anaconda 3. Now my script works using conda-execute but I get the WARNING: g++ not detected, cannot perform optimizations.
 
As a result I used `conda install gcc` and added conda's gcc path using Theano's cxx flag but now I get the error `fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?